# RAL to RGB/HEX via javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner when it comes to javascript...I got a project which requires the following:

Conversion from RAL-Color-Codes to RGB/HEX (javascript).

I overthought that and came across some ideas:

1.) Make a complex list which inherits all RAL-Codes (around 213+)

2.) to be DRY - get RAL-to-RGB/HEX-Information from: http://www.ralcolor.com/

Well - as I said: I'm a beginner in javascript...

It would be very nice if you could give me some hints to start the coding, as I'm a media-designer, not a programmer :(

Best regards,
daft

Comment: The easiest thing you could do is parse the table from the ralcolor.com website and get the values of the td's which will give you the ral-colour hex and rgb value

Comment: okay, thanks for your help =) I will try to find out how to parse html code from a website ;) - would you recommend a tutorial source or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short example of parsing the table itself. This is my standard template `blank.html` file with the addition of 4 rows of the table and some code in mInit.

A few things to consider, in no particular order:

- It seems that every 2nd table row is empty
- The rgb values use the `-` as a separator, rather than `,`
- It seems unlikely that you'd want the hex code and the rgb code. If you give the(some?) browser a # code, it converts it internally to an rgb() code. (Chrome 32.0.1700.102 m) If this is suitable, just grab the hex-code, since it doesn't need to be altered with a RegEx like the rgb value does.
- you can have a look around http://w3schools.com for documentation of the various functions/attributes I've used.

**Output:** (excerpt)

```
There are 4 rows in the table
RAL 7046: rgb: 130,137,143 - hex: #82898F
RAL 7047: rgb: 208,208,208 - hex: #D0D0D0
```

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////    U n u s e d   i n   t h i s   s a m p l e
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function newEl(tag) {
  return document.createElement(tag);
}

function newTxt(txt) {
  return document.createTextNode(txt);
}

function toggleClass(element, newStr) {
  var index = element.className.indexOf(newStr);
  if (index == -1)
    element.className += ' ' + newStr;
  else {
    if (index != 0)
      newStr = ' ' + newStr;
    element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
  }
}

function forEachNode(nodeList, func) {
  var i, n = nodeList.length;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////    R e q u i r e d   b y   t h i s   s a m p l e
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function byId(e) {
  return document.getElementById(e);
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit() {
  var tbl = byId('colTable');
  var rows = tbl.rows
  var output = '';
  var i, n, curRowNum, curRowOfCells;

  output = "There are " + rows.length + " rows in the table" + "<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    curRowOfCells = rows[i].cells;
    if (rows[i].cells[0].childNodes.length != 0) {
      var curRalCode, curRgb, curHex;

      curRalCode = rows[i].cells[0].querySelectorAll('p span')[0].innerHTML;

      curRgb = rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
      // change 130-137-143 into 130,137,143
      curRgb = curRgb.replace(/-/g, ',');

      curHex = rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

      output += curRalCode + ": " + "rgb: " + curRgb + " - hex: " + curHex + "<br>";
    }
  }
  byId('output').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>
<table id='colTable'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="HEIGHT: 50px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">RAL 
          7046</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)" align="center"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">130-137-143</span></td>
    <td style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)" align="center"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">#82898F</span></td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegrau 2</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegrey 2</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegris 2</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Gris&nbsp;tele 2</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Tele 
          grigio 2</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(130,137,143)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegrijs 2</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="HEIGHT: 50px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">RAL 
          7047</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)" align="center"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">208-208-208</span></td>
    <td style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)" align="center"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">#D0D0D0</span></td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegrau 4</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegrey 4</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegris 4</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Gris 
          tele 4</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Tele 
          grigio 4</span></p>
    </td>
    <td style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.75pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-TOP: 0.75pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0.75pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.75pt; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(208,208,208)">
      <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Telegrijs 4</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you VERY MUCH enhzflep for your effort! I need some time to work through your code to understand the whole thing ;) I'd give you a +1 but don't have enough points to do so :(

Comment: :grin: A pleasure, daftpanda. The sentiment is more than enough. If the code helps you, I've succeeded!

Comment: thank you enhzflep! I cannot take for granted that someone helps me with such a great effort like you did! =)

Comment: if you need to find only few colors, just put RALs into textarea and you'll get rgb in output: https://jsfiddle.net/us325451/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @gregmatys - That's a good solution. You should consider posting it as an answer, since it correctly performs the conversion from a RAL code to an RGB one and mine merely relies on the data already being present. Your approach seems like the far better one to me. :)