# Convert RAL to HEX color code

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Is it possible to convert [RAL color code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAL_colour_standard) to a HEX color code by code? 
I have a table with a lot of RAL color codes and i want to display them in my view somehow. If there is a way by just using css that would be great to.

Comment: convert where? you have tagged this with a server language and javascript? What research have you done? A web search should provide you some clues

Comment: If your list of color codes is in  Cielab [Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAL_colors) your question is convert Lab -> RGB, right? [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ral+color&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=convert+Lab+color+to+RGB) will help.

Comment: [Here is a solution: RAL to RGB/HEX via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476457/ral-to-rgb-hex-via-javascript)

Comment: I have a list with a lot of RAL codes and i want to show the codes in CSS by setting the value like background-color: #333333 but i need to convert my RAL into rgb or hex to be able to use css?

Comment: @DavidArno - your duplicate does not actual convert

Comment: Convert the table http://www.ralcolor.com/ to a lookup table and use  var hex = table[ral]`

Comment: @mplungjan, I agree, so I retracted it. Marked it as a duplicate for discussion and discovered I had the power to close it all by myself. I don't like that responsibility :)

Comment: I wield the DupeHammer (Mjölnir) too, but try to make sure it is not just a dupe by name

Comment: thanks for all the quick answers! I will probably go with the ralcolor.com table and make that as a js-file so that i can do a quick lookup. thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan, yep now I know I can close as duplicate, I'll be more careful with it in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the table at ralcolor.com to a lookup table and use that as follows:

```js
const getHex = ral => rals["RAL" + ral];
const hr = document.getElementById('hr')
hr.title = 4003;
hr.style.height = "20px";
hr.style.backgroundColor = getHex(hr.title); // RAL4003

// demo of all RAL colours in order of HEX string
document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = Object.entries(rals)
  .sort((entryA, entryB) => {
    const hexA = entryA[1], hexB = entryB[1]
    return (hexA < hexB) ? -1 : (hexA > hexB) ? 1 : 0;
  })
  .map(([ral,hex]) => `<div style="background-color: ${hex}" title="${hex}">${ral}</div>`)
  .join("");
```

```css
div { display:inline-block; padding: 2px; margin:2px; width:auto; }
```

```html
<hr id="hr" />
<div id="colors"></div>

<script>
const rals = { "RAL1000": "#BEBD7F", "RAL1001": "#C2B078", "RAL1002": "#C6A664", "RAL1003": "#E5BE01", "RAL1004": "#CDA434", "RAL1005": "#A98307", "RAL1006": "#E4A010", "RAL1007": "#DC9D00", "RAL1011": "#8A6642", "RAL1012": "#C7B446", "RAL1013": "#EAE6CA", "RAL1014": "#E1CC4F", "RAL1015": "#E6D690", "RAL1016": "#EDFF21", "RAL1017": "#F5D033", "RAL1018": "#F8F32B", "RAL1019": "#9E9764", "RAL1020": "#999950", "RAL1021": "#F3DA0B", "RAL1023": "#FAD201", "RAL1024": "#AEA04B", "RAL1026": "#FFFF00", "RAL1027": "#9D9101", "RAL1028": "#F4A900", "RAL1032": "#D6AE01", "RAL1033": "#F3A505", "RAL1034": "#EFA94A", "RAL1035": "#6A5D4D", "RAL1036": "#705335", "RAL1037": "#F39F18", "RAL2000": "#ED760E", "RAL2001": "#C93C20", "RAL2002": "#CB2821", "RAL2003": "#FF7514", "RAL2004": "#F44611", "RAL2005": "#FF2301", "RAL2007": "#FFA420", "RAL2008": "#F75E25", "RAL2009": "#F54021", "RAL2010": "#D84B20", "RAL2011": "#EC7C26", "RAL2012": "#E55137", "RAL2013": "#C35831", "RAL3000": "#AF2B1E", "RAL3001": "#A52019", "RAL3002": "#A2231D", "RAL3003": "#9B111E", "RAL3004": "#75151E", "RAL3005": "#5E2129", "RAL3007": "#412227", "RAL3009": "#642424", "RAL3011": "#781F19", "RAL3012": "#C1876B", "RAL3013": "#A12312", "RAL3014": "#D36E70", "RAL3015": "#EA899A", "RAL3016": "#B32821", "RAL3017": "#E63244", "RAL3018": "#D53032", "RAL3020": "#CC0605", "RAL3022": "#D95030", "RAL3024": "#F80000", "RAL3026": "#FE0000", "RAL3027": "#C51D34", "RAL3028": "#CB3234", "RAL3031": "#B32428", "RAL3032": "#721422", "RAL3033": "#B44C43", "RAL4001": "#6D3F5B", "RAL4002": "#922B3E", "RAL4003": "#DE4C8A", "RAL4004": "#641C34", "RAL4005": "#6C4675", "RAL4006": "#A03472", "RAL4007": "#4A192C", "RAL4008": "#924E7D", "RAL4009": "#A18594", "RAL4010": "#CF3476", "RAL4011": "#8673A1", "RAL4012": "#6C6874", "RAL5000": "#354D73", "RAL5001": "#1F3438", "RAL5002": "#20214F", "RAL5003": "#1D1E33", "RAL5004": "#18171C", "RAL5005": "#1E2460", "RAL5007": "#3E5F8A", "RAL5008": "#26252D", "RAL5009": "#025669", "RAL5010": "#0E294B", "RAL5011": "#231A24", "RAL5012": "#3B83BD", "RAL5013": "#1E213D", "RAL5014": "#606E8C", "RAL5015": "#2271B3", "RAL5017": "#063971", "RAL5018": "#3F888F", "RAL5019": "#1B5583", "RAL5020": "#1D334A", "RAL5021": "#256D7B", "RAL5022": "#252850", "RAL5023": "#49678D", "RAL5024": "#5D9B9B", "RAL5025": "#2A6478", "RAL5026": "#102C54", "RAL6000": "#316650", "RAL6001": "#287233", "RAL6002": "#2D572C", "RAL6003": "#424632", "RAL6004": "#1F3A3D", "RAL6005": "#2F4538", "RAL6006": "#3E3B32", "RAL6007": "#343B29", "RAL6008": "#39352A", "RAL6009": "#31372B", "RAL6010": "#35682D", "RAL6011": "#587246", "RAL6012": "#343E40", "RAL6013": "#6C7156", "RAL6014": "#47402E", "RAL6015": "#3B3C36", "RAL6016": "#1E5945", "RAL6017": "#4C9141", "RAL6018": "#57A639", "RAL6019": "#BDECB6", "RAL6020": "#2E3A23", "RAL6021": "#89AC76", "RAL6022": "#25221B", "RAL6024": "#308446", "RAL6025": "#3D642D", "RAL6026": "#015D52", "RAL6027": "#84C3BE", "RAL6028": "#2C5545", "RAL6029": "#20603D", "RAL6032": "#317F43", "RAL6033": "#497E76", "RAL6034": "#7FB5B5", "RAL6035": "#1C542D", "RAL6036": "#193737", "RAL6037": "#008F39", "RAL6038": "#00BB2D", "RAL7000": "#78858B", "RAL7001": "#8A9597", "RAL7002": "#7E7B52", "RAL7003": "#6C7059", "RAL7004": "#969992", "RAL7005": "#646B63", "RAL7006": "#6D6552", "RAL7008": "#6A5F31", "RAL7009": "#4D5645", "RAL7010": "#4C514A", "RAL7011": "#434B4D", "RAL7012": "#4E5754", "RAL7013": "#464531", "RAL7015": "#434750", "RAL7016": "#293133", "RAL7021": "#23282B", "RAL7022": "#332F2C", "RAL7023": "#686C5E", "RAL7024": "#474A51", "RAL7026": "#2F353B", "RAL7030": "#8B8C7A", "RAL7031": "#474B4E", "RAL7032": "#B8B799", "RAL7033": "#7D8471", "RAL7034": "#8F8B66", "RAL7035": "#C5C7C4", "RAL7036": "#7F7679", "RAL7037": "#7D7F7D", "RAL7038": "#B5B8B1", "RAL7039": "#6C6960", "RAL7040": "#9DA1AA", "RAL7042": "#8D948D", "RAL7043": "#4E5452", "RAL7044": "#CAC4B0", "RAL7045": "#909090", "RAL7046": "#82898F", "RAL7047": "#D0D0D0", "RAL7048": "#898176", "RAL8000": "#826C34", "RAL8001": "#955F20", "RAL8002": "#6C3B2A", "RAL8003": "#734222", "RAL8004": "#8E402A", "RAL8007": "#59351F", "RAL8008": "#6F4F28", "RAL8011": "#5B3A29", "RAL8012": "#592321", "RAL8014": "#382C1E", "RAL8015": "#633A34", "RAL8016": "#4C2F27", "RAL8017": "#45322E", "RAL8019": "#403A3A", "RAL8022": "#212121", "RAL8023": "#A65E2E", "RAL8024": "#79553D", "RAL8025": "#755C48", "RAL8028": "#4E3B31", "RAL8029": "#763C28", "RAL9001": "#FDF4E3", "RAL9002": "#E7EBDA", "RAL9003": "#F4F4F4", "RAL9004": "#282828", "RAL9005": "#0A0A0A", "RAL9006": "#A5A5A5", "RAL9007": "#8F8F8F", "RAL9010": "#FFFFFF", "RAL9011": "#1C1C1C", "RAL9016": "#F6F6F6", "RAL9017": "#1E1E1E", "RAL9018": "#D7D7D7", "RAL9022": "#9C9C9C", "RAL9023": "#828282" };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this site if I need HEX for RAL Colors or other Color Tables
https://colors.watch/color-tables/ral-classic
Very helpfull site, you can select image or take photo and detect RAL color or find alternative colors